# How do I get the unique elements from an array of hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, unique

I have an array of hashes, and I want the unique values out of it.  Calling `Array.uniq` doesn't give me what I expect.

```
a = [{:a => 1},{:a => 2}, {:a => 1}]
a.uniq # => [{:a => 1}, {:a => 2}, {:a => 1}]
```

Where I expected:

```
[{:a => 1}, {:a => 2}]
```

In searching around on the net, I didn't come up with a solution that I was happy with.  Folks recommended redefining `Hash.eql?` and `Hash.hash`, since that is what `Array.uniq` is querying.

Edit:
Where I ran into this in the real world, the hashes were slightly more complex.  They were the result of parsed JSON that had multiple fields, some of which the values were hashes as well.  I had an array of those results that I wanted to filter out the unique values.

I don't like the redefine `Hash.eql?` and `Hash.hash` solution, because I would either have to redefine `Hash` globally, or redefine it for each entry in my array. Changing the definition of `Hash` for each entry would be cumbersome, especially since there may be nested hashes inside of each entry.

Changing `Hash` globally has some potential, especially if it were done temporarily. I'd want to build another class or helper function that wrapped saving off the old definitions, and restoring them, but I think this adds more complexity than is really needed.

Using `inject` seems like a good alternative to redefining `Hash`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I can get what I want by calling `inject`

```
a = [{:a => 1},{:a => 2}, {:a => 1}]
a.inject([]) { |result,h| result << h unless result.include?(h); result }
```

This will return:

```
[{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}]
```

Comment: much more better I think than the one link I posted above

Answer (score 19):

Ruby 1.8.7+ will return just what you have expected:

```
[{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}, {:a=>1}].uniq
#=> [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}]
```

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar situation, but hashes had keys. I used sorting method.

What I mean:

you have an array:

```
[{:x=>1},{:x=>2},{:x=>3},{:x=>2},{:x=>1}]
```

you sort it (`#sort_by {|t| t[:x]}`) and get this:

```
[{:x=>1}, {:x=>1}, {:x=>2}, {:x=>2}, {:x=>3}]
```

now a bit modified version of answer by Aaaron Hinni:

```
your_array.inject([]) do |result,item| 
  result << item if !result.last||result.last[:x]!=item[:x]
  result
end
```

I've also tried:

```
test.inject([]) {|r,h| r<<h unless r.find {|t| t[:x]==h[:x]}; r}.sort_by {|t| t[:x]}
```

but it's very slow. here is my benchmark:

```
test=[]
1000.times {test<<{:x=>rand}}

Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report("sorting: ") do
    test.sort_by {|t| t[:x]}.inject([]) {|r,h| r<<h if !r.last||r.last[:x]!=h[:x]; r}
  end
  bm.report("inject: ") {test.inject([]) {|r,h| r<<h unless r.find {|t| t[:x]==h[:x]}; r}.sort_by {|t| t[:x]} }
end
```

results:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
sorting:    0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.005633)
inject:     0.470000   0.140000   0.610000 (  0.621973)
------------------------------------ total: 0.620000sec

                user     system      total        real
sorting:    0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.003839)
inject:     0.480000   0.130000   0.610000 (  0.612438)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your hashes are always single key-value pairs, this will work:

```
a.map {|h| h.to_a[0]}.uniq.map {|k,v| {k => v}}
```

Hash.to_a creates an array of key-value arrays, so the first map gets you:

```
[[:a, 1], [:a, 2], [:a, 1]]
```

uniq on Arrays does what you want, giving you:

```
[[:a, 1], [:a, 2]]
```

and then the second map puts them back together as hashes again.

Comment: The real world problem that I came across used more complex hashes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use (tested in ruby 1.9.3),

```
[{a: 1},{a: 2},{a:1}].uniq => [{a:1},{a: 2}]
[{a: 1,b: 2},{a: 2, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 3}].uniq_by {|v| v[:a]} => [{a: 1,b: 2},{a: 2, b: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you give is similar to the one discussed [here](http://mikeburnscoder.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/uniquify-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby/). It overrides the `hash` and `eql?` methods on the hashes that are to appear in the array which then makes `uniq` behave correctly.

Comment: That is one of the solutions I found on the net.  I didn't like that I needed to redefine hash, just to call uniq.

Comment: If the vanilla Hash and Array classes don't do what you need you should really consider defining your own classes that implement the required behaviour.

Can you describe what it is you are trying to model with arrays of hashes?

Answer (score 0):

found on google 
http://mikeburnscoder.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/uniquify-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

The pipe method on arrays (available since 1.8.6) performs set union (returning an array), so the following is another possible way to get unique elements of any array `a`:

`[] | a`

Comment: @SunnyRGupta, what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: `ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]`

Comment: @SunnyRGupta, I don't know what to say. I just tested again, and it works perfectly.
    $ irb
    1.9.3p448 :001 > a = [{:a => 1},{:a => 2}, {:a => 1}]
     => [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}, {:a=>1}] 
    1.9.3p448 :002 > [] | a
     => [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}]