# How do I get unique elements in this array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Mongoid. Unfortunately, Mongoid does not allow for selecting unique / distinct! 
Have gotten these results. As you can see, there are 7 results. If you look carefully (at user_id), there are only 2 users.

```
[
  #<Activity _id: 4cea6c4572357e00fa00011a, created_at: 2010-11-22 13:12:37 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 13:12:37 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea2fb872357e00fa000025'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea447472357e00fa00009a')>, 
  #<Activity _id: 4cea6c3072357e00fa000116, created_at: 2010-11-22 13:12:16 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 13:12:16 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea2fb872357e00fa000025'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea447472357e00fa00009a')>, 
  #<Activity _id: 4cea6bdd72357e00fa00010d, created_at: 2010-11-22 13:10:53 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 13:10:53 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea2fb872357e00fa000025'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea447472357e00fa00009a')>, 
  #<Activity _id: 4cea46df72357e00fa0000a4, created_at: 2010-11-22 10:33:03 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 10:33:03 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea2fb872357e00fa000025'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea447472357e00fa00009a')>, 
  #<Activity _id: 4cea40c572357e00fa00006f, created_at: 2010-11-22 10:07:01 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 10:07:01 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea2fb872357e00fa000025'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea3c8b72357e00fa00005e')>, 
  #<Activity _id: 4cea3ca172357e00fa000062, created_at: 2010-11-22 09:49:21 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 09:49:21 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea39b772357e00fa000046'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea3c8b72357e00fa00005e')>, 
  #<Activity _id: 4cea344a72357e00fa00003f, created_at: 2010-11-22 09:13:46 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 09:13:46 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea2fb872357e00fa000025'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea306c72357e00fa000031')>
]
```

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181091/how-do-i-get-the-unique-elements-from-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby), and was thinking I could do something similar so that my array would now look like this:

```
[
  #<Activity _id: 4cea6c4572357e00fa00011a, created_at: 2010-11-22 13:12:37 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 13:12:37 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea2fb872357e00fa000025'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea447472357e00fa00009a')>, 
  #<Activity _id: 4cea3ca172357e00fa000062, created_at: 2010-11-22 09:49:21 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-22 09:49:21 UTC, action: "Attend", user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea39b772357e00fa000046'), artist_id: nil, media_id: BSON::ObjectId('4cea3c8b72357e00fa00005e')>
]
```

I'm not concerned which combination of results are extracted. As long as I have unique user_id's in the result set. Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can just use the method `uniq`. Assuming your array is `ary`, call:

```
ary.uniq{|x| x.user_id}
```

and this will return a set with unique `user_id`s.

Comment: This is a quick solution to the OP's problem, but in the long run encourages slurping all data in then iterating over it to remove the duplicates. That will consume more resources than necessary. A better solution is for the OP to use a smarter query that eliminates the dupes up front, or a collection-type that eliminates them by its nature.

Comment: @Greg: yep, I agree, but be sure you aren't doing premature optimization either...

Comment: That's not premature, it's 30+ years of experience dealing with databases.

Comment: @Peter It returns an Array not a Set. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html

Answer (score 16):

This should work for you:

Consider Table1 has a column by the name of **activity** which may have the same value in more than one record. This is how you will extract ONLY the unique entries of **activity** field within Table1.

```
#An array of multiple data entries
@table1 = Table1.find(:all) 

#extracts **activity** for each entry in the array @table1, and returns only the ones which are unique 

@unique_activities = @table1.map{|t| t.activity}.uniq
```

Answer (score 11):

For those hitting this up in the future, you can now use the `Mongoid::Criteria#distinct` method from Origin to select only distinct values from the database:

```
# Requires a Mongoid::Criteria
Attendees.all.distinct(:user_id)
```

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html (v3.1.0)

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at this page?

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct

That might save you some time?

eg
db.addresses.distinct("zip-code");

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an Array, consider using either a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) or a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Set.html).

Sets behave similar to an Array, only they contain unique values only, and, under the covers, are built on Hashes. Sets don't retain the order that items are put into them unlike Arrays. Hashes don't retain the order either but can be accessed via a key so you don't have to traverse the hash to find a particular item.

I favor using Hashes. In your application the user_id could be the key and the value would be the entire object. That will automatically remove any duplicates from the hash.

Or, only extract unique values from the database, like John Ballinger suggested.

Comment: N.B. from Ruby 1.9 the order is maintained for hashes, and so I would presume, sets. Happy to be corrected if I'm wrong on the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Errr, it's a bit messy in the view. But I think I've gotten it to work with group (http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/)

Controller

```
@event_attendees = Activity.only(:user_id).where(:action => 'Attend').order_by(:created_at.desc).group
```

View

```
<% @event_attendees.each do |event_attendee| %>    
  <%= event_attendee['group'].first.user.first_name %>
<% end %>
```