# Return unique values from Jekyll collection / data source

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I have a JSON data source in the `_data` folder of a Jekyll site that looks like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "March",
    "year": "2014"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "May",
    "year": "2013"
  },
    ....
  }
```

I'd like to list the unique values of the *year* attribute. The following returns a list of years; I'd like just the unique years.

```
<ul>
{% for playlist in site.data.playlists %}
  <li>
    {{ playlist[1].year }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Tried messing around with assigning variables so that I can use what's given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252164/how-do-i-get-unique-elements-in-this-array) but with no luck, and I'm not sure it will work in Jekyll anyway.

---

Comment: Can you provide json data file ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel added example JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to group playlist by year.

**_data/playlists.json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "March",
    "year": "2014"
  },
  {
    "name": "May",
    "year": "2013"
  },
  {
    "name": "December",
    "year": "2013"
  }
]
```

Note that we here have an array of hashes.

You can now group playlists by year an loop over :

```
{% comment %} ++++ Group playlists by year ++++ {% endcomment %}
{% assign grouped = site.data.playlists | group_by: "year" %}

<ul>
{% for year in grouped %}
  <li>
    {{ year.name }}
    <ul>
    {% for item in year.items %}
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only process once equal elements，these code may work:

```
<ul>
{% assign s_year = null %}
{% assign t_year = null %}
{% for playlist in site.data.playlists %}
{% capture t_year %}{{playlist[1].year}}{% endcapture %}
{% if t_year == s_year %}{% else %}
<li>
{{ t_year }}
</li>
{% endif %}
{% capture s_year %}{{ t_year }}{% endcapture %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```