# Rails 3. Distinct query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails 3 application (which acts as an API) and I allow
people to send in a bunch of email address (via an iPhone app) and then automatically
search the database for matching members (through emails).

It is working now (below code) but is returning doubles if the user sends in more than one copy of each email.

```
@users = @emails.find_all {|profile| User.find_by_email(profile['email']) }
```

I want the api to only return one unique copy of the user if found.
I tried the below code but it does not work.

```
@users = @emails.find_all {|profile| User.select('DISTINCT email').where("LOWER (email) = ?", "%#{profile['email']}%") }
```

How can the first line of code above be changed to distinct lookups?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at

[How do I get the unique elements from an array of hashes in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181091/how-do-i-get-the-unique-elements-from-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby)

```
a = [{:a => 1},{:a => 2}, {:a => 1}]
a.inject([]) { |result,h| result << h unless result.include?(h); result }
# this returns : [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}]
```

Seems like to be what you need!

Comment: Looks very interesting. How can I transform @users = @emails.find_all {|profile| User.find_by_email(profile['email']) } to use your syntax? Please help!

Comment: I used your code to "clean" the incoming hash of emails and it works great now! Thanks!

Comment: this works nicely by itself, but will break if you also use pagination , e.g. Kaminari, and use .page(n) afterwards; as the inject() will return an Array.

Comment: Inject is going to be much slower than using uniq or group on the relation, especially when the query returns a lot of rows.